# There is an error in the public void Setup().The error is The method Setup() is undefined for the type jammytestappium

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, appium

Below code has an error is at the setup location.Why is this error coming up?? .The error is as follow:

```
There is an error in the public void Setup().
The error is The method Setup() is undefined for the type jammytestappium.
```

This was causing harm while executing the code.

My code looks as follows:

```
 package com.example.jamappium;
    import java.net.MalformedURLException;
    import java.net.URL;
    import java.sql.Driver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
    import org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.handler.FindElement;
    import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;
    import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.SetupApi;
    import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
    import io.appium.java_client.remote.AndroidMobileCapabilityType;
    import io.appium.java_client.remote.MobileCapabilityType;

    public class Jammytestappium {
         {
            AndroidDriver<WebElement> abcd;
            @BeforeClass 
            public void setup()
            {
                DesiredCapabilities test=new DesiredCapabilities();
                test.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_PACKAGE,
                            "com.veronicapps.veronica.simplecalculator");
                test.setCapability(AndroidMobileCapabilityType.APP_ACTIVITY,
               "com.veronicapps.veronica.simplecalculator.MainActivity");
                test.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.VERSION, "4.2.2");
                test.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "emulator");
                abcd = (AndroidDriver) new RemoteWebDriver(new URL(
                        "http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"),test);
            }
        }
```

Comment: First of all you not following java conventions, make the classname uppercase and method name should start with smallerCase letter.Second of all the description should me more detailed.

Comment: I am giving an elaborate description because what might be useful for me might also be useful for some other person.If the description is elaborate and a beginner can understand it why not give it a go??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the extra braces after "public class jammytestappium {"

Comment: Thanks a ton!!Was not able to figure out that brace from 2 days!!:)

Comment: This question was caused by a  simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.